I'm using Python (and BeautifulSoup) to convert XML into HTML. Can I get just what's inside an XML tag, skipping the tag's own attributes?
I'm processing some XML into HTML, using Python which passes some variable strings to a Python template. I use BeautifulSoup to retrieve and parse the XML I want.
Given this XML snippet:
<item key="68">
    <interview titleBib="22582" title="Harvey Birdman - Session III" bib="22582-3" interviewer="Phil Ken Sebben" location="Memphis, Tennessee" dateSingleRaw="1997-06-16T12:00:00Z" dateSingleRawTime="Mon, 06/16/1997 - 12:00" dateMultipleRaw="" abstractRaw="<p>Some of the topics discussed include: his childhood; </p>">
        <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
            <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
                    <h3>Sebben:</h3>
                    <p>This is the text of the interview.</p>
                    <h3>Birdman:</h3>
                    <p>That's correct.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </interview>
</item>

I have an "interview" variable which captures that entire "interview" tag with all its attributes and contents. I would like to have a "transcript" variable which contains only what's between the "interview" tags, with none of that tag's many attributes. So my "transcript" variable value would be:
<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
            <h3>Sebben:</h3>
            <p>This is the text of the interview.</p>
            <h3>Birdman:</h3>
            <p>That's correct.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

The relevant part of my Python code is:
    interview = get_transcript(bn)
    interviewer=""
    date=""
    location=""
    transcript=""
    if interview is not None:
        interviewer = interview.get('interviewer')
        date = interview.get('dateSingleRawTime')
        location = interview.get('location')
        transcript = interview
    out = htmltemplate.substitute(title=title, interviewer=interviewer, date=date, location=location, 
                                    transcript=transcript)

Naturally this does not get what I want into the "transcript" variable; I get the entire  tag. Can I use Python to get just the content between the tags? Thank you.

use element.encode_contents()

Thanks GTK. This gets close to the desired effect, but not quite. The main issue is that the contents of the "abstractRaw" attribute remain, possibly because of the paragraph tags. This is the one element which was really causing problems for me. It also adds the visible text "\n" between every new line, which I could easily clean up.

what do you mean "abstractRaw" remains? it works fine for me with the provided html, and encode_contents() returns a bytestring, you can use interview.encode_contents().decode('utf-8') to get a 'clean' string.

IIUC, if you want the tag inside <interview> you can use .find():
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_text = """\
<item key="68">
    <interview titleBib="22582" title="Harvey Birdman - Session III" bib="22582-3" interviewer="Phil Ken Sebben" location="Memphis, Tennessee" dateSingleRaw="1997-06-16T12:00:00Z" dateSingleRawTime="Mon, 06/16/1997 - 12:00" dateMultipleRaw="" abstractRaw="<p>Some of the topics discussed include: his childhood; </p>">
        <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
            <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
                    <h3>Sebben:</h3>
                    <p>This is the text of the interview.</p>
                    <h3>Birdman:</h3>
                    <p>That's correct.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </interview>
</item>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_text, "html.parser")

interview = soup.select_one("interview")

tag_inside_interview = interview.find()
print(tag_inside_interview)

Prints:
<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
<h3>Sebben:</h3>
<p>This is the text of the interview.</p>
<h3>Birdman:</h3>
<p>That's correct.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

